# Javascript does not recognize function

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, dom

I am new to programming in Javascript and this one has clearly 'clean bowled' me :(........

The following code snippet highlights some text by searching for and modifying the respective text nodes. Text node searching is done by using a Jquery functionality:

> window.addEventListener("load", highlightSummarySentences , false);

```
function highlightSummarySentences() {
    var docName = thisPage;
    var numSentences = getCookie(docName+"Num");
    var linkSentenceNum = getCookie(docName + 'LinkingSentence');
    for(var i=0; i<numSentences; i++) {
        var matchMe = getCookie(docName+i);
        try {
            if (matchMe && i==(linkSentenceNum)) {
                highlightText(matchMe, clickedSentenceColour);
            }
            else if(matchMe){
                highlightText(matchMe, summarySentenceColour);
            }
        } catch (e) {;
        }
    }
}
```

The for loop runs once and highlights the appropriate text after which it exits and the page becomes completely white. The following error is seen in the error console:

> Error: getCookie is not defined

but I guess its not getCookie. The script just refuses to recognize any function or variable after the above event. I have no idea what might be causing the script to behave this way. I am developing in firefox.

Please give me a hint! Let me know if I should paste more code of give more information.

Thanks,

Comment: where did you declare that function? and when do you call add event listener? probably a timing issue

Comment: `var docName = thisPage;` What would be thisPage? is it a global var? Can you check the complete script? I use firebug on firefox and chrome/Opera also has similar dev tools

Comment: did u intialize `setCookie` before using `getCookie`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your description(page clears after 1st loop) sounds like you use somewhere `document.write()`.

Do you? (could be in highlightText())

If yes: you can't use write() after a document is loaded, write() will overwrite all contents, js too, so all functions defined somewhere doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: I do not use document.write but I do modify HTML of text nodes by adding span elements to highlight the sentence. The code although works well on many web pages.

Answer (score 8):

`getCookie()` is not a function provided by the browser.  This snippet probably expects a `getCookie()` function to be declared somewhere in your code.  `document.cookie` is what you would use to get the cookie string from a browser, but you have to parse and split it to find the data you need.  This is what a `getCookie` function you write would do for you.

Comment: Yep I have written getCookie to do exactly that and it is defined in the script.

Comment: Well it can't be found at the time this snippet executes if that is the error message you are getting.  So either it's declared wrong, or not at all, or within an inaccessible scope.

Comment: It is very surely not declared wrong. It might somehow be getting out of scope. Dr. Molle below suggest a reason. But still the code runs on most of the pages. I can paste the highlighter code here somewhere if someone is eager to have a look at it.

Answer (score 4):

Add this getCookie() function in your page

```
function getCookie(cname) {
     var name = cname + "=";
     var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
     for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if(c.indexOf(name) == 0)
           return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
     }
     return "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are tagging jquery, I recommend you to do the following:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   window.addEventListener("load", highlightSummarySentences , false); });
</script>
```